# Finding minimum x such that Mod[3^x, m] == 1 for m not multiple of 3

Tags: number-theory

I would like to find smallest x value for each m value such that `Mod[3^x, m] == 1`, where `m` is not multiple of 3.

Here is my try, which is not optimal for large `m`, say `m >= 10000`. How can I write a condition in `Table`, so that whenever the condition `Mod[3^x, m] == 1` holds, the computation breaks and proceeds to the next `m` value?

A different approach would also be welcome.

```
range = 100;
m = Complement[Range[2, range], Range[3, range, 3]];
sol = ParallelTable[Mod[3^x, m[[i]] ] , {i,  Length @ m}, {x, range}];
pos = FirstPosition[#, 1] & /@ sol;
Transpose @ {m, Flatten @ pos}
```

**Edit** Here is two different and faster method I found. First time I am using `While` and `Break` in my code :)

```
range = 10;
m = Complement[Range[2, range], Range[3, range, 3]];
val = (x = 1; While[x <= range, If[Mod[3^x, #] == 1, Break[]]; x++]; 
     x) & /@ m;
Transpose@{m, val}
```

> {{2, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 4}, {7, 6}, {8, 2}, {10, 4}}

```
range = 10;
m = Complement[Range[2, range], Range[3, range, 3]];
val = Last@
      Reap@Do[If[Mod[3^x, #] == 1, Sow@x; Break[]], {x, range}] & /@ 
    m // Flatten;
Transpose@{m, val}
```

> {{2, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 4}, {7, 6}, {8, 2}, {10, 4}}

**Edit 2** I realized one can use `Throw` and `Catch` functions.

```
range = 10;
m = Complement[Range[2, range], Range[3, range, 3]];
val = Catch@Table[If[Mod[3^x, #] == 1, Throw@x], {x, range}] & /@ m
Transpose@{m, val}



range = 10;
m = Complement[Range[2, range], Range[3, range, 3]];
val = Catch@Do[If[Mod[3^x, #] == 1, Throw@x], {x, range}] & /@ m
Transpose@{m, val}
```

Comment: Lookup the function [`MultiplicativeOrder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiplicativeOrder)

Comment: Wow! I was not aware that function. Thanks. `{#, MultiplicativeOrder[3, #]} & /@ m`

Comment: I think that Euler's Theorem may be helpful for this, it can be used to find an x quickly, but I'm not sure about the finding the lowest such x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this question can be answered by a link to the documentation of [`MultiplicativeOrder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiplicativeOrder.html), I think something more should put on record because `MultiplicativeOrder` can not be expected to be known or easy to find for Mathematica beginners.

First we generate the search space.

```
searchSpace =
  With[{max = 100}, Module[{r = Range[2, max]}, Pick[r, Not /@ Divisible[r, 3]]]];
```

And now we use `MultiplicativeOrder` to generate the requested table, which we then plot.

```
ListPlot[{#, MultiplicativeOrder[3, #]} & /@ searchSpace,
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, 15}},
  AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question is now how can we solve this problem without `MultiplicativeOrder`. I wanna learn efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci. That you were more interested in the algorithm and its implementation than in making computations with it is not at all clear in your question. However, you should not bring the issue up in a comment to an answer. You should edit the question to bring the community's attention to it.